# Ifdef in C using crossplatform Android/iOS doesn´t work propertly

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I have a piece of code to change calls between different platforms. But I have detected a problem using iphone and ipad, TARGET_OS_IPHONE definition only works with iphone, but no ipad, I don´t want to try using else to think is ipad because maybe in the future this will be a source of problems.

I have lost 2 days looking for a problem with colors in opencv matrix caused by this.....

My question, exist a proper solution official to execute a piece of code in iOS S.O (Iphone AND Ipad)?

As reference, I look always in [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/) link.

An example to select code:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    // All linux arch
#elif _WIN32
    // Windows 32 and 64
#elif __APPLE__
    #ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
         // iOS, no work with iPAD
    #elif TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        // iOS Simulator
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
        // Other kinds of Mac OS
    #else
        // Unsupported platform
    #endif
#elif __ANDROID__
  // Android all versions
#else
  //  Unsupported architecture
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including "TargetConditionals.h" file in case of '__APPLE__'.
This file includes all the macros refered to the Apple devices.

Any way, using your example, the correct way should be:

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
// All linux arch
#elif _WIN32
// Windows 32 and 64
#elif __APPLE__
    #include "TargetConditionals.h"     // <--- Include this
    #ifdef TARGET_OS_IOS                // <--- Change this with a proper definition
    // iOS, including iPhone and iPad
    #elif TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    // iOS Simulator
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    // Other kinds of Mac OS
    #else
    // Unsupported platform
#endif
#elif __ANDROID__
// Android all versions
#else
//  Unsupported architecture
#endif
```

Also, you can let 'TARGET_OS_IPHONE' definition there, but 'TARGET_OS_IOS' is more appropiate.

You can include this file directly, or you can find it in your disk following the path: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/TargetConditionals.h'.

Comment: Oh! it seems I miss that header when move pieces of code to another project. It provide all macros I was looking for.... Thanks a lot!